# Selenium automatic login can be used on web pages; can it also be used on Android apps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried automating Facebook login using Selenium WebDriver. Can I do the same automatic login on Android applications instead of web pages? And if yes, what dependency do I need? Or do I need some sort of API?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is no selenium dosen't supp mobile app but you can use Appium a good free open source tool.

Answer (score 0):

One option how I do it is to run the android app in an emulator such as Android Studio on Windows, and then use a Windows automation tool like AppRobotic Personal to simulate user actions, allowing me to log in on the android app.